# Canvas.drawCircle() with large circles under hardware acceleration

Tags: android

In the course of developing an Android application, I'm finding a need to draw
several unfilled concentric circles centered on an arbitrary point, enough that
some of them are only partly visible on the display.  However, this does not
appear to work with hardware acceleration.  My test rig is a stock Samsung Galaxy
Tab 10.1 running Android 3.2.

The following code comes from a test subclass of View I wrote to isolate the
issue:

```
private Paint paint = new Paint();

private int count = 0;

private static final int[] COLORS = { 0xffff0000, 0xff00ff00, 0xff0000ff, 0xffff00ff };

public TestCircles(Context context) {
    super(context);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(1.0f);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
}

public TestCircles(Context context, AttributeSet attributes) {
    super(context, attributes);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(1.0f);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
}

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
    if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        invalidate();
    return true;
}

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    // Pick the color to use, cycling through the colors list repeatedly, so that we can
    // see the different redraws.
    paint.setColor(COLORS[count++]);
    count %= COLORS.length;

    // Set up the parameters for the circles; they will be centered at the center of the
    // canvas and have a maximum radius equal to the distance between a canvas corner
    // point and its center.
    final float x = canvas.getWidth() / 2f;
    final float y = canvas.getHeight() / 2f;
    final float maxRadius = (float) Math.sqrt((x * x) + (y * y));

    // Paint the rings until the rings are too large to see.
    for (float radius = 20; radius < maxRadius;
            radius += 20)
        canvas.drawCircle(x, y, radius, paint);
}
```

I am running TestCircles as the only View in an Activity, laying it out to fill
the available width and height (i.e. it is nearly full-screen).  I can tap on
the display (triggering redraws) only a few times before the redraws no longer
occur (i.e. the circles' color doesn't change).  Actually, the onDraw() code is
still running in response to each tap -- as proven with diagnostic messages --
but nothing changes onscreen.

When onDraw() first starts to fail to redraw, the debug log includes the
following entry, once for every call to onDraw():

> E/OpenGLRenderer(21867):   OpenGLRenderer is out of memory!

If I turn off hardware acceleration in the manifest, these problems go away --
not surprising since clearly OpenGL is having problems -- and actually it is
a good deal faster than the few times it actually works under hardware
acceleration.

My questions are:

1. Am I misusing Canvas, or is this a bug, or both?  Is Android allocating large
   bitmaps under the hood to draw these circles?  It doesn't seem like this should be
   this challenging to OpenGL, but I'm new to hardware accelerated app development.
2. What's a good alternative way to draw large unfilled circles that have portions
   extending out of the clipping region of the Canvas?  Losing hardware acceleration
   is not an option.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

I've since learned from others that the problem I described here is the result of a bug in Android 3.2.  The workaround for now is of course to use a software layer instead of hardware acceleration.  Apparently this problem is fixed in Android 4.0 (Ice Cream Sandwich).

Comment: Unfortunately not; I asked this same question on the Google android-developers group, and Romain Guy from the Android team at Google explained that this was a 3.2 bug fixed in 4.0; the workaround is of course to use software rendering instead of hardware acceleration.